# How to avoid google API access code or access token by C#

Tags: c#, google-api, google-sheets-api

I'm developing an application to insert row to one of my spreadsheet (like database). The problem is, it always asking new access code. Please help me to avoid expiring the access code or I just want to update my google drive account excel. Sometimes there will be a easy code, may I using wrong code? Below is my code:

```
string CLIENT_ID = "HIDE";
string CLIENT_SECRET = "HIDE";
string SCOPE = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds https://docs.google.com/feeds";
string REDIRECT_URI = "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob";

OAuth2Parameters parameters = new OAuth2Parameters();
parameters.ClientId = CLIENT_ID;
parameters.ClientSecret = CLIENT_SECRET;
parameters.RedirectUri = REDIRECT_URI;

parameters.Scope = SCOPE;
string authorizationUrl = OAuthUtil.CreateOAuth2AuthorizationUrl(parameters);
auth.Text = authorizationUrl;
info.Text = ("Please visit the URL above to authorize your OAuth " +"request token.  Once that is complete, type in your access code to "+ "continue...");
parameters.AccessCode = accc.Text;

OAuthUtil.GetAccessToken(parameters);
string accessToken = parameters.AccessToken;
acc2.Text =  accessToken;

GOAuth2RequestFactory requestFactory =
                          new GOAuth2RequestFactory(null, "MySpreadsheetIntegration-v1", parameters);
SpreadsheetsService service = new SpreadsheetsService("MySpreadsheetIntegration-v1");
                      service.RequestFactory = requestFactory;
                      string USERNAME = "HIDE";
                      string PASSWORD = "HIDE";

                      service.setUserCredentials(USERNAME, PASSWORD);

                      SpreadsheetQuery query = new SpreadsheetQuery();

                      SpreadsheetFeed feed = service.Query(query);

                      if (feed.Entries.Count == 0)
                      {
                          Console.WriteLine("None");
                      }

                      SpreadsheetEntry spreadsheet = (SpreadsheetEntry)feed.Entries[0];
                      Console.WriteLine(spreadsheet.Title.Text);

                      WorksheetFeed wsFeed = spreadsheet.Worksheets;
                      WorksheetEntry worksheet = (WorksheetEntry)wsFeed.Entries[0];

                      AtomLink listFeedLink = worksheet.Links.FindService(GDataSpreadsheetsNameTable.ListRel, null);


                      ListQuery listQuery = new ListQuery(listFeedLink.HRef.ToString());
                      ListFeed listFeed = service.Query(listQuery);

                      ListEntry row = new ListEntry();
                      row.Elements.Add(new ListEntry.Custom() { LocalName = "no.", Value = "#" });
                      service.Insert(listFeed, row);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make a request for "offline" access when requesting the access token.  The server will return a "refresh token" and with this toke you can request a new "access token" when it expires without having the user to grant permissions again.

[Here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#offline) you can find documentation on that.

Check [this](http://gusclass.com/blog/2014/04/16/how-to-oauth-2-0-flows-using-the-google-net-api-client-libraries-1-7-in-c/) tutorial, it will help you to obtain the access token and refresh token programmatically instead of having to open the browser and copy the token.